# I can vote twice on a single post from the 10k tools

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools

I recently gained access to the mod tools on StackOverflow, (woot!) and I've noticed something a little odd. When I vote on a post, it will *usually* show me a message like:

> "You need X more votes to [action] the post."

However, after a while, if I reload the flagged posts or the edit queue, ***I can vote again***.

I don't know if it's caused by waiting for a certain amount of time or by another person flagging after me, or perhaps something else. (I think it would be a time issue, since I am pretty sure that I've single handedly approved some edits.) While this *could* be my mind playing tricks. I'm fairly certain its not. (I'm having trouble reproducing this consistently, but I've seen several posts where, after voting I though "Wait, I just voted on that earlier".

Edit:

I've seen this with edit and close votes.

Comment: Do you mean stuff like voting to close? Does the vote count shown on the post increase after you vote a second time?

Comment: I think you mean the 10k tools, not the moderator ones. :-)

Comment: @Cody They're called ["moderator tools"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) in the list of privileges. Not entirely accurate, but oh well.

Comment: Clarified the question.

Comment: Certain types of flags can be cast at the same time on the same post by the same user (not the _same_ flag, but different flags).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> While this could be my mind playing tricks. I'm fairly certain its not.

I'm fairly certain it is :) If you take action on a flag (i.e., vote to close), then it displays a pop-up saying "x more votes needed" and stays there. If you try to vote again, you will not find an option to choose - it just shows what you've already chosen.

If you refresh the page, the little counter on the top by the `flags` tab will decrease by 1 (i.e., if in the mean time a mod hasn't dismissed a flag) and that post will no longer be displayed to you.

[image]

On the other hand, it is possible that there are two different flags on the same post (e.g., an exact duplicate flag and a not-constructive flag.) and you could technically act on both of them. You can disagree with both of them or agree with one and disagree with the other or agree with both but certainly not cast a close vote on both flags.

Another possibility is that you might have added a flag agreeing with the existing ones *and* voted to close. (Note that voting to close and adding a flag saying that it should be closed is really an absurd thing to do and will only piss off the mods. Not that you did it, but just leaving it here.)

---

The behaviour for edit queue is the same, except that if you're casting the second vote on any action, it automatically folds it and hides it out of your view. There really is no way you can cast two votes on the same question.

Comment: So if two people flag a post, I can vote once per flag? That sounds like it might be it.

Comment: I think it's got to be two different flag reasons (i.e., exact dupe vs. too long or off-topic, etc)... If more than one flag for the same reason, it just displays a `x N` where `N` is the number of people who have agreed with that. I've never had this (two flags on the same post) happen to me, but that's the most likely explanation.

Comment: So I'm not imagining things. Can we get ac onfirmation from someone who can access the code?

Comment: No, you are imagining things. You said you could close again, and that I'm very sure that you cannot do (believe me, there are posts that I wish I could vote more than once!). What I meant was that you could flag a question multiple times. You can try it out yourself. Flag a post, then flag it again. The reason this is allowed is because if you made a mistake, you could use a second flag to explain that your first flag was incorrect. Or if there have been new developments and the first flag still hasn't been resolved, you could explain it in a second flag.

Comment: In short, if there are two different flags on one question, you can address each of them individually. However, you cannot cast a close vote on the question for each of them.

Comment: @Moshe confirmed; both "close" votes and the "support / invalid-flag" options have checks in *at the server* to prevent duplicate voting (even if the UI allowed it, i.e. you pressed "back")